# Python - ConfigParser throwing comments

Tags: python, configparser

Based on ConfigParser module how can I filter out and throw every comments from an ini file?

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("sample.cfg")

for section in config.sections():
    print section
    for option in config.options(section):
        print option, "=", config.get(section, option)
```

eg. in the ini file below the above basic script prints out the further comments lines as well like:

```
something  = 128     ; comment line1
                      ; further comments 
                       ; one more line comment
```

What I need is having only the section names and pure key-value pairs inside them without any comments. Does ConfigParser handles this somehow or should I use regexp...or? Cheers

Comment: What does "throw out" mean?  Please provide a clear statement of what you're really trying to do -- why do you need to "throw out" data from a file?  Where does it go?  What's left behind?

Answer (score 5):

according to [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) lines starting with `;` or `#` will be ignored. it doesn't seem like your format satisfies that requirement. can you by any chance change format of your input file?

**edit**: since you cannot modify your input files, I'd suggest pre-parsing them with something along the lines:

```
tmp_fname = 'config.tmp'
with open(config_file) as old_file:
    with open(tmp_fname, 'w') as tmp_file:
        tmp_file.writelines(i.replace(';', '\n;') for i in old_lines.readlines())
# then use tmp_fname with ConfigParser
```

obviously if semi-colon is present in options you'll have to be more creative.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to write a commentless `file` subclass:

```
class CommentlessFile(file):
    def readline(self):
        line = super(CommentlessFile, self).readline()
        if line:
            line = line.split(';', 1)[0].strip()
            return line + '\n'
        else:
            return ''
```

You could use it then with configparser (your code):

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(CommentlessFile("sample.cfg"))

for section in config.sections():
    print section
    for option in config.options(section):
        print option, "=", config.get(section, option)
```

Comment: I think there's a small typo there, it should be super(CommentlessFile, self).readline(), instead of CommentRemover.

Comment: @sykora: I fixed that 5 seconds after the first post :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems your comments are not on lines that *start* with the comment leader. It should work if the comment leader is the first character on the line.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am not allowed to modify the input ini file.In this format of ini file as I noticed all the comment lines are appended to the value part of last key - except the first comment line (right after value) which is dropped indeed.

Comment: In fact my task is to compare two ini files (every significant part except comments)

Comment: Then you'll probably have to create a temporary file and/or use ConfigParser.readfp() to scrap the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 comes with a build-in solution: The class [configparser.RawConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/configparser.html?highlight=rawconfigparser#rawconfigparser-objects) has constructor argument `inline_comment_prefixes`. Example:

```
class MyConfigParser(configparser.RawConfigParser):
    def __init__(self):
      configparser.RawConfigParser.__init__(self, inline_comment_prefixes=('#', ';'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As the doc said: "(For backwards compatibility, only ; starts an inline comment, while # does not.)" So use ";" and not "#" for inline comments. It is working well for me.